# How to prefill edit boxes when my custom dialog is shown from the custom action script in my MSI?

Tags: c++, wix, windows-installer

I'm using WiX to create a custom dialog/page in my installer, based on WixUI_Mondo. The custom dialog has edit controls, similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="ConfigDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.SetupTypeDlg_Title)" >
                
                <Control Id="idTxt11" Type="Text" X="20" Y="65" Width="60" Height="16" Text="Name:" />
                <Control Id="idEdt11" Type="Edit" X="90" Y="60" Width="120" Height="20" Default="yes" Property="PROP_NAME" />

                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>

            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I can read those controls from my custom action DLL (written in C++) when the Next button is clicked, by invoking it as such:

```
<Publish Dialog="ConfigDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="idCA_NextBtn">1</Publish>
```

but I also need to pre-populate those edit boxes when the page is first shown (by reading these values from the registry). This may be needed if someone is upgrading or repairing my software.

The question is, how do I do that from my custom action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each property that you need read from the registry (for upgrades/repairs) just add a `<RegistrySearch>` element that populates those properties.